# WPF packaged with MSIX unable to pass Microsoft Store validation

Tags: wpf, uwp-xaml, windows-store, desktop-bridge, msix

Microsoft Store is unable to validate the `.msixupload` file packaged by Visual Studio. The solution file consists of a WPF app, a UWP app for XAML Island, and the MSIX Packaging Project.

The error returned at the Partner Center site is:

> Package acceptance validation error: You cannot submit pre-compiled
> .NET Native packages. Please upload the Microsoft Store appxupload
> file and try again.

The `.msix` generated along with the `.msixupload` can be installed and run locally with no issues. It also passes the Windows App Cert Kit tests.

What is the potential cause of this validation error? Searched high and low for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to UWP project in MSIX Packaging Project.